# How to run codes in node shell?

Tags: node.js

FYI i'm a total noob.I have downloaded windows installer version from node.js site.I am on win 7.This is what i typed in to test

```
$ node
console.log("Hello World");
```

But after hitting enter it doesn't do anything,just goes to the next line showing "..." .What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a file xyz.js and then on command Prompt run node xyz.js. It will show you the output hello world.

Comment: But shouldn't just executing `node` open the [repl](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html)?

Comment: It should But if it still gives an error as mentioned in question this would work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In macOSX,

`$ node` shows

`>` with prompt cursor in the next line.

Then

`console.log("Hello World");`

shows

```
Hello World
undefined
```

perhaps console.log is evaluated to undefined.

Anyway, it works as should be.
Just let you know, you do nothing wrong in theory as far as I know.

I just don't know for windows box.